# m80 macro assembler org directive

Tags: assembly, z80, cpm

I am using Microsoft's ancient m80 macro assembler and haven't run into any major problems for a while.

However, I am now trying to use the ORG directive with a hex number and it fails.

This works:

```
;; Tell the assembler that this is z80 code                                                                                                          
.Z80

;; Start program after zero page                                                                                                                     
ASEG
ORG     100h
```

However, this does not work:

```
;; Set assembler to B00
ORG     B00h
```

m80 claims it's a fatal error:

```
I>A:M80 =TEST/M
%No END statement
U                                       ORG     B00h
%No END statement

1 Fatal error(s)
```

How can I use the ORG directive with a number that contains digits above 9?

What am I missing?

Comment: I think you need a leading zero, e.g. `ORG 0B00h`, otherwise it looks like an arbitrary symbol rather than a hex constant.

Comment: Hey! That's it. Should have noticed it myself! Make it an answer and I'll accept it! Ta!

Comment: Great - comment now converted to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a leading zero, e.g. `ORG 0B00h`, otherwise it just looks like an arbitrary symbol, rather than a hex constant.